# Drawing and writing something up and down corner inside a square

Tags: diagrams

In LaTeX, how can I write something up and down (corner) inside a square?

I know how to draw a square, but I don't know how to put them. More, what will I do if I have more than one square? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you show us how you draw a square or draw it in paint and post here what it should look like? The better you describe the problem the better we can answer it.

Comment: Also, please provide a Minimal Working Example, as there are many ways to do this in Latex. At least, show how you draw the square.

Comment: I think, it's too early for a downvote, after 20min. Give the OP some time to improve the post

Answer (score 1):

I really haven't a clue what you're after, but here's my best attempt at interpreting:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[anchor=north west]
  \draw (0,0) coordinate (ll1) rectangle ++(3,3) coordinate (ur1);
  \node[rotate=90] at (ll1) {something up};
  \node[rotate=-90] at (ur1) {something down};
  \draw (4,2) coordinate (ll2) rectangle ++(2.5,2.5) coordinate (ur2);
  \node[rotate=90] at (ll2) {another up};
  \node[rotate=-90] at (ur2) {another down};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you can clarify your needs, I will improve/update this answer.